# Matplotlib whole legend leftaligned

Tags: matplotlib, alignment, legend

I would like to align left all the elements of the legend (natively, only the title is left aligned).
Any idea on how to achieve that?

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib 
_plot = plt.plot(range(5), range(5), label = 'a') 
legend = plt.legend(loc = 'upper left', title = 'this is a long title')`

Comment: Can you show us some code that reproduces the problem you are seeing?

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib
_plot = plt.plot(range(5), range(5), label = 'a')
legend = plt.legend(loc = 'upper left', title = 'this is a long title')`
The following produces a line and an a in the center, not on the left.

Comment: @FlavienLambert Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that ?
[image]

if so you can get it with:

```python
x = arange(1.0, 15, 1.0)
plot(x,log(x),label=r'$y=log(x)$')
plot(x,5*x,label=r'$y=5x$')
plot(x,5*x+log(x),label=r'$y=5x+log(x)$')
plot(x,x**2,label=r'$y=x^2$')
legend(loc='upper left')
show()
```